# Measure query execution time excluding start-up cost in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to measure the total time taken by postgres to execute my query excluding the start-up cost. Earlier I was using \timing but now I found \timing includes start-up cost.

I also tried: "explain analyze" in which I found that actual time is specified in a particular format like: actual time=12.04..12.09
So, does this mean that the time taken to execute postgres query excluding start-up time is 0.05. If not, then is there a way to exclude start-up costs and measure query execution time?

Comment: What do you mean by "startup cost"? What exactly you want to leave out of measurement?

Comment: @depesz since postgres usually keeps general stuff like schemas in memory therefore I want to exclude that cost. This is what I meant by start-up cost

Comment: Execute it twice? Execute it twice (after prepare) with different parameters?

Comment: @wildplasser I can not execute it twice..because if I do then postgres  will cache the results. I want to measure query execution time after clearing caches...and after excluding start-up cost

Comment: There are two kinds of cahed results: 1) the plan 2) the actual data. Repeating the query with different parameters will cache (1), but not (2) [unless your table fits in memory, in which case there won't be any problem]

Answer (score 3):

What you want is actually quite ill-defined.

"Startup cost" could mean:

- network connection overhead and back-end start cost of establishing a new connection. Avoided by re-using the same session.
- network round-trip times for sending the query and getting the results. Avoided by measuring the timing server-side with `log_statement_min_duration = 0` or (with timing overhead) using `explain analyze` or the `auto_explain` module.
- Query planning time. Avoided by `PREPARE`ing the query, then timing only the subsequent `EXECUTE`.
- Lock acquisition time. There is not currently any way to exclude this.

Note that using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` may not be ideal for your purposes: it throws the query result away, and it adds its own costs because of the detailed timing it does. I would set `log_statement_min_duration = 0`, set `client_min_messages` appropriately, and capture the timings from the log output.

So it sounds like you want to `PREPARE` a query then `EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE` it or just `EXECUTE` it with `log_statement_min_duration` set to 0.

Comment: Start-up cost for me is Query planning time. How can I prepare the query..and time only the subsequent execute. Actually if i time only the subsequent execute then I would get faster results as the results would then be cached. Which I dont want.

Comment: @EmmeWatson Er... I said how to do that, and you even used the right words. `PREPARE` the query, then time the `EXECUTE`. For caching effects, well, that's harder, and not what you asked about originally. Read up on PostgreSQL benchmarking - how to scale the benchmark appropriately, how to drop/flush caches, etc. Search.

Answer (score 0):

For exploring PLANNING costs and EXECUTE costs separately you need to set on several postgres.conf parameters:

```
log_planner_stats = on
log_executor_stats = on
```

and explore your log file.

Update: 
1. find your config file location with executing:

```
SHOW config_file;
```

2. Set parameters. Don't foget to remove comment-symbol '#'.
3. Restart postgresql service
4. Execute your query
5. Explore your log file.

Comment: Since I am a complete novice at it..so I am not getting how to..can you please give some initial guidance..rest i'll try to figure out